# Не может найти главный класс

Tags: maven

Делаю проект Maven с использованием библиотеки javaFx , при сборке проекта ошибок ни каких нет , при сборке через команду javafx:run тоже ошибок никаких нет , но! Непосредственно когда запускаешь собранный jar файл через cmd **java MavenProject4-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*** выдает ошибку (**Error: Could not find or load main class MavenProject4-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**) Вот мой pom.xml код `

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenProject4</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->

</dependencies>



<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>Main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>



    </plugins>


</build>
```

`
Вот моя иерархия папок

[image: Иерархия папок]

Помогите , я уже все перепробовал

Answer (score 0):

Крч когда я запустил через cmd jar командой -> (java -jar example.jar) он выдал ошибку которая звучала так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда я понял что дело в версии , а именно я собрал проект под 14 версию а пытался запустить с 1.8

- И так решение ->(скачать jdk 1.8 и выбрать ее при созданий проекта в IDE)
  B все заработает!